# Displaying icons for filetypes in KendoEditor FileBrowser

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I'm using kendo editor and it's Image and File Browsers.
I can see thumbnais for each of the image files in the Image Browser (like an image manager).
What I wanted to do was to see icons, in a similar way of the thumbnais, but for  the files in the FileBrowser. The Icon would idealy be of the filetypes of each file (example: PDF, TXT...).

Is there a way of associating any type of icon to the files in the fileBrowser window?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do the same thing. I just did a `setInterval` that checks if the file browser window exists, and change the image if it does. Here's my code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $(".k-reset.k-floats.k-tiles.k-widget.k-listview.k-selectable").find("strong").each(function(e) {
        // case insensitive search for files that end with .pdf
        if(this.innerText.match(/\.pdf$/i)) {
            // apply css style for the span that holds the image and replace with your own
            $(this).siblings().find("span").css({ "background": "#fff url('path/to/your/image') no-repeat center" });
        }
    });
}, 1);
```

There's probably a better way, but this works. Not to mention nobody else except us needs to do this apparently. I've been searching Google for days for a proper way to do this.